# Attoparsec parse fails but shouldn't with proper backtracking

Tags: regex, haskell, backtracking, parsec, attoparsec

I am using Attoparsec which is said to backtrack by default. However, the following line:

```
parseOnly  (string "foo" *> many1 anyChar <* string "bar") "fooxxxbar"
```

fails with:

```
Left "not enough input"
```

Why is that so? If `many1 anyChar` decides to parse only three characters (`xxx`) it should be successful. And it should consider doing that at some point because of backtracking, shouldn't it?

What is the proper way to do equivalent of `/foo(.*)bar/` regex using Attoparsec?

Answer (score 2):

> I am using Attoparsec which is said to backtrack by default.

Not quite. Attoparsec *does* support backtracking, but only in some explicit situations (where the documentation says it does). Its purpose is high-performance parsing and, unsurprisingly, that doesn't play well with backtracking.

You are looking for [`manyTill`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.1.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Combinator.html#v:manyTill) or `manyTill'`. Note that the backtracking behaviour is mentioned in the documentation.

```
ghci> manyTill1 p e = (:) <$> p <*> manyTill p e 
ghci> parseOnly (string "foo" *> manyTill1 anyChar (string "bar")) "fooxxxbar"
Right "xxx"
```

Comment: Well, the documentation explicitly says: "attoparsec parsers always backtrack on failure". What parser combinators are there with full backtracking support? Performance is not an issue for me and the proposed solution with `manyTill` does not work well for my use case.

Comment: @IguanaBob [regex-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative) does not backtrack but will always succeed if it is possible to. [ReadP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) has the same property and can parse more grammars. [ReadS](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#t:ReadS) is basically a less efficient ReadP, and does actually backtrack -- but I consider "backtracking" to be an implementation detail for the real property you care about, which all three satisfy.